# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'global.crypto') error after bundling with Parcel

Tags: node.js, express, bundler, parcel

I have EXPRESS app that includes browser facing javascript files that inturn import several node packages like nodemailer and dotenv. After bundling scripts.js the browser displays an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'global.crypto')
```

[image: Error stack]

This results in scripts.js file not being executed.

Tree:

```
public
  css
  js
    dist
      scripts.js
      scripts.js.map
    scripts.js
    email.js
    alerts.js
views
app.js
package.json
```

List of browser facing javascript files:

```
scripts.js
alerts.js
email.js
```

Description: 
`scripts.js` imports a function from email.js, listens for a form submit, and sends email. `alert.js` adds a child `div` with the message onto a screen and email sent successfully.

Package imports: 
`email.js` imports node mailer and dotenv/config

Parcel installation V8.19.2:

```
npm i parcel --save-dev
```

Parcel commands:

```
"watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/scripts.js --dist-dir ./public/js/dist  ",
"build:js": "parcel build ./public/js/scripts.js --dist-dir ./public/js/dist"
```

I am using `EJS`, bundled js files added at the very end:

```
 <script src="/js/dist/scripts.js" type="module"></script>
 <noscript> Your browser does not support JavaScript! </noscript>
</body>
```

Tried virtually everything that I was able to find online.

Current package.json:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "SOME NAME",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "SOME WEB SITE",
  "main": "app.js",
  "targets": {
    "main": false
  },
  "browserslist": "> 0.25%, not dead",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon app.js",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon app.js",
    "watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/scripts.js --dist-dir ./public/js/dist  ",
    "build:js": "parcel build ./public/js/scripts.js --dist-dir ./public/js/dist"
  },
  "author": "DR",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "core-js": "^3.32.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^6.8.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "hpp": "^0.2.3",
    "html-to-text": "^9.0.5",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "ratelimit": "^0.0.4",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.14.0",
    "xss": "^1.0.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "punycode": "^1.4.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "url": "^0.11.1",
    "util": "^0.12.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^18"
  }
}
```

I tried to add:

```
"browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "stream": false
  },
```

I tried to play with:

```
targets": {
      "main": {
         "includeNodeModules": true
      }
   }
```

I tried to play with:

```
targets": {
      "default": {
         "includeNodeModules": true
      }
   }
```

When I add `"includeNodeModules": true` a new error pops up saying about not being able to find 'fs' module.

##### TEMPORARY SOLUTION:

I got rid off parcel, added axios CDN to make a post request from scripts.js on submit event.